# Accelerate Clipper, Performance Tuning

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I'am using a Clipper transformer in my workbench with ~30.000 features of clippers an ~20 clippees and running it takes a lot of time.

**So I was wondering if there is any possibility to accelerate the clipper transformer,** espacially beacause I'm using it more than once in my workbench.

I already had a look at this: https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/579/performance-tuning-fme.html
So I removed all Attributes before, feature caching is disabled.

I thought, maybe some preprocessing might help like usinge an Aggregator or dissolver, but it didn't seem to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options.

The best chance of improvement is to make sure the Clipper features arrive at the transformer first (make them the first reader or use a Sorter to sort the data) and then switch the Clipper Type parameter to Clippers First.

This will make more efficient use of the memory resources and so - hopefully - speed things up.

Another method would be - if you are using a Group By - to arrange features to arrive in group order. Then you can set Group By Mode to Process When Group Changes.

That too would make more efficient use of memory. The problem there is that arranging features to arrive in group order when there are two input ports is quite difficult.

Alternatively, if you *are* using a Group By (or if you can divide the data another way), consider putting the transformer inside a Custom Transformer and turning on parallel processing. This blog post explains how to do parallel processing: https://www.safe.com/blog/2019/01/parallel-processing-2019-evangelist183/

But for parallel processing, a lot depends on the state of the data.

If the features all overlap, then you can't really spread it into separate groups because they would get processed separately and not properly interact.

But if the Clippees (or Clippers) are spread out, then you could always create a separate process for each Clippee feature, or for each set of X features. I can't really be any more precise without knowing what your data looks like. Probably the Clippers would be what you want to split up, since there are so many of them.

The idea is - of course - that if you can run multiple processes simultaneously then it should be quicker overall. It would help to have a lot of memory available and be using a multi-core/multi-CPU machine for this.

Hope this helps. It's fairly broad, but if you can provide more info about your data, then we could be more precise with an answer.